# Unable to import scipy library using Flask & Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, scipy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to set up a Flask web app using Elastic Beanstalk on AWS. I have followed the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) and that works fine. I am now looking to expand the Flask webapp, and this works fine, until I `import scipy.spatial as spatial`, when this is part of my import statements, running eb open just times out. I receive

```
>>>> HTTP ERROR 504
```

running the webapp locally works absolutely fine even with the scipy import, it is only when I try and deploy to beanstalk that it doesn't want to work. Below is my code

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import scipy.spatial as spatial  ##### Removing this and everything works!

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify

# print a nice greeting.
def say_hello(username = "World"):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]})
    return '<p>Hello %s!</p>\n' % username

# some bits of text for the page.
header_text = '''
    <html>\n<head> <title>EB Flask Test</title> </head>\n<body>'''
instructions = '''
    <p><em>Hint</em>: This is a RESTful web service! Append a username
    to the URL (for example: <code>/Thelonious</code>) to say hello to
    someone specific.</p>\n'''
home_link = '<p><a href="/">Back</a></p>\n'
footer_text = '</body>\n</html>'

# EB looks for an 'application' callable by default.
application = Flask(__name__)

# add a rule for the index page.
application.add_url_rule('/', 'index', (lambda: header_text +
    say_hello() + instructions + footer_text))

# add a rule when the page is accessed with a name appended to the site
# URL.
application.add_url_rule('/<username>', 'hello', (lambda username:
    header_text + say_hello(username) + home_link + footer_text))

# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Setting debug to True enables debug output. This line should be
    # removed before deploying a production app.
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

I have tried increasing the command timeout for the environment from 600 to 900, although the timeout error occurs well before 600 seconds has elapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I am not sure why this is the case but I updated the version of scipy in my requirements.txt and the app is working as expected!

Originally I had

```
scipy==1.4.1
```

Now I have

```
scipy==1.2.3
```

I have no idea why this has fixed the deployment issue, especially given 1.4.1 works perfectly locally. If anyone has an idea, or if this a bug I should be reporting it would be good to know!